# Unit Testing Component in AngularJS 1.5 and Typescript

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

Working on converting some old broken AngularJS unit tests to TypeScript and came across this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myComponentDirectiveProvider <- myComponentDirective
```

In every example of AngularJS unit testing I've seen, they have a main module with everything on it, and they inject that main module into the unit test with `angular.mock.module('theWholeStinkingApp')`.  That is nice for a little tutorial, but I'm dealing with a very large application with hundreds of components and dozens of services.  Not to mention filters and other directives.  It doesn't work to just inject the whole app into a unit test.  Nor do I think it's a good idea to start up the whole app just to unit test a component (kind of defeats the purpose of unit testing when you have to include everything you own in every test).

For testing services I can just create my module in the test in a `beforeEach` like this, so I'm mocking dependencies, but injecting the real service I want to test:

```
angular.mock.module(($provide) => {
  $provide.service('firstDependency', FirstDependencyMock);
  $provide.service('secondDependency', SecondDependencyMock);
  $provide.service('serviceIWantToTest', ServiceIWantToTest);
});
```

I can't figure out how to do this and inject a Component.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Please keep in mind, I do not want to have to `angular.mock.module('theWholeApp')` to get this working.  I just want to create a mock module and attach my component to it.**

Here's a slimmed down version of what I'm doing.

Component looks something like this

```
angular.module('theWholeApp', [])
  .component('myComponent', {
    controller: MyComponentController, // class is defined elsewhere
    templateUrl: 'path/to/my/template.html'
  )
  ... // 100+ other components;
```

Here's the test:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // angular.mock.module('theWholeApp'); This is not an option.

    // Creating a mock module with just the dependencies I need for this test
    angular.mock.module(($provide) => {
        $provide.service('firstDependency', FirstDependencyMock);
        $provide.service('secondDependency', SecondDependencyMock);
    });

    // Tried adding this to register the controller, but it doesn't help.  
    angular.mock.module(($controllerProvider) => {
        $controllerProvider.register('MyComponentController', MyComponentController);
    });

    angular.mock.inject(($injector) => {
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $componentController = $injector.get('$componentController');
      firstDependency= $injector.get('firstDependency');
      secondDependency= $injector.get('secondDependency');

      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });
  });

  describe('doSomething', () => {
    it('exists', () => {
      controller = $componentController('myComponent', {$scope});
        expect(controller.doSomething).toBeDefined();
      });
  });
});
```

Obviously, this isn't the live code, just a representation.  Hopefully I got all the made up names right.  The point is, I want to create a mock module and add my component to it so a call to `$componentController('myComponent', {$scope})` works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the answer I came up with is deceptively simple, but I've never seen it done anywhere.  If anyone can tell me why it's a bad idea and suggest something better, I'm all for it.

The answer is to just create the module you want then immediately add it to the test.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {

  // Create a new module with the things you need.
  // Putting it outside the "beforeEach" because it only needs to be created once.
  angular.module('myComponentTestModule', [])
    .component('myComponent', {
      controller: MyComponentController, // class is defined elsewhere
      templateUrl: 'path/to/my/template.html'
    )
    .service('firstDependency', FirstDependencyMock)
    .service('secondDependency', SecondDependencyMock);

  beforeEach(() => {

    // Add the new module to the test suite
    angular.mock.module('myComponentTestModule');

    angular.mock.inject(($injector) => {
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $componentController = $injector.get('$componentController');
      firstDependency= $injector.get('firstDependency');
      secondDependency= $injector.get('secondDependency');

      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });
  });

  describe('doSomething', () => {
    it('exists', () => {
      controller = $componentController('myComponent', {$scope});
        expect(controller.doSomething).toBeDefined();
      });
  });
});
```